# How to fix UnicodeDecode error in django in this scenario?

Tags: python, django, database, postgresql

I want to order the model objects in descending order, how am I supposed to go about doing that using the field `number` in my model class.

Here is my views.py:

```
class SeasonDetailView(DetailView):
  
    model = CartoonSeason
    template_name = "episode_list.html"

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context["episodes"] = Episode.objects.filter(season=self.object)
        return context



class EpisodeDetailView(DetailView):
  
    model = Episode
    template_name = "episode.html"
```

And this is my models.py:

```
class Episode(models.Model):
    season = models.ForeignKey(CartoonSeason, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    number = models.IntegerField()
    cover  = models.URLField(max_length=300, blank=True, null=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=False)
    link = models.URLField(max_length=300, blank=True, null=True)
    published = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True, null=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class Episode(models.Model):
    season = models.ForeignKey(CartoonSeason,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    number = models.IntegerField()
    cover  = models.URLField(max_length=300, blank=True, null=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=False)
    link = models.URLField(max_length=300, blank=True, null=True)
    published = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True, 
    blank=True,null=True)


    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _("Episode")
        verbose_name_plural = _("Episodes")
        ordering = ["season"]
```

Comment: please consider adding explanation to the code for easier understanding.